# When can we manually select Save Draft button?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I am not sure when the `Save Draft` button should be available to (or enabled for) users. I want to be sure to explain this feature correctly and am not sure if I'm looking at an environment issue or if I'm just missing expected behavior. Does this sound right?

1. While editing text in the UI Update (Experience Manager or XPM), the `Save Draft` button appears unavailable (grayed out) until I change fields or otherwise click *off* of a given component presentation.
2. Then for a brief moment, before XPM saves a minor change (e.g. "version 1.1") to the edited component, the `Save Draft` button is available and appears *click-able*.
3. It quickly becomes grayed out again.

In case its meant for page changes, if I insert a new component presentation, XPM will prompt me with "All changes have been saved" and `Save Draft` isn't available.

**Are there scenarios where I would be able to manually press `Save Draft`?** And is clicking outside of a field the right way to have XPM recognize we've made changes to a component (and save minor changes), for just a selected component?

*Session preview isn't enabled for this environment, if it happens to affect the button's behavior.*

**Edit:** I found one scenario where the button stays available: edit a text field then select the `Properties` button in the toolbar. The `Save Draft` button will become available and stay selectable until you click elsewhere. :-)

To be clear, I don't care that XPM saves changes quickly and that `Save Draft` is rarely available. I'm just wondering when we'd actually need it. Maybe it'd be okay to remove it in a GUI extension even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the button being enabled right after making a content change (and clicking outside of the inline editable field, i.e. by selecting the next inline editable field of that Component Presentation). It stays enabled for me as long as I keep editing this Component Presentation, as soon as I click outside of the current Component Presentation, I see the button becoming disabled again (at that point Experience Manager has auto-saved my changes).

So I think what you are seeing is expected behavior, as soon as a change is auto-saved, the button becomes disabled again.

As to if there are scenarios when you would want to manually press this button, I'm not sure. Guess it depends on your browsing behaviour, if you often (maybe accidentally) click the cross to close the tab or browser window, then your save might be at risk. So in that case you will want to click the button after every change. But normally I think the auto-save feature has it covered for you and you don't need to bother.

Comment: Ok, the docs confirm that changes are saved if the `Save Draft` button is disabled. In the component presentations I'm looking at, the button won't stay available even if clicking in the same CP. This does look like expected behavior. +1 and accepted, thanks!